# How to do convert the following ino lambda expression(method syntax)?

Tags: c#, linq

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

var pairs =
    from a in numbersA
    from b in numbersB
    where a < b
    select new { a, b };
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/190e1fdf-0b38-4d30-ac52-59c8d15f771a/c-possible-lambda-in-arrays-content-declaration?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Init array of type with lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368492/init-array-of-type-with-lambda)

Comment: See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/ for how query expressions are translated.

Comment: Please don't undo the edit that made your post *so* much clearer to read, showing code *as code*.

Comment: why? If it's not broke don't fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var pairs = numbersA.SelectMany(a => numbersB.Where(b => b>a)
                    .Select(b => new { a, b }));
```

Please see this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RZvUwH)

What does `SelectMany` ?

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So from the result of the `SelectMany` that would contain all the combinations between the current `a` and all the numbers in the `numbersB` array, which are greater than `a`, we select an anonymous type with two properties, `a` and `b`. Doing this for all the numbers in `numbersA` we get that we want.